# ITEXT print symbol ← or ⇄

Tags: itext

I need to write the subject character in itext.

I've found the MAP-tables of HEX code in this URL:

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=%E2%86%90&preview=entity

This is my actually line of the code

```
Phrase titolo = new Phrase("test try \u2190",FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 10, Font.BOLD, new BaseColor(0, 0, 0));
```

But don't work.

Comment: You have to find a font supporting that character.

Comment: Helvetica only has a limited set of characters. It doesn't know the `\u2190`. Moreover you are using a *simple font* that can physically hold only 256 characters. You should use a *composite font* that can hold 65,535 character and that should be embedded in the PDF (because otherwise not every viewer will know how to render that character).

Comment: @Bruno: there are default font in iText with 65.535 char that can I use?

Comment: No, there is no default font in iText that you can embed. You have to provide one yourself.

Comment: I'm going to close your question as a duplicate, because I checked and I discovered that the Cardo family of fonts knows how to display that character. Please read the answer to the duplicate question to solve your problem (and to learn where to download Cardo-Regular).